# Is it reasonable to claim that given a specific value of the independent variable(s), each fun has at most 1 gradient? how to prove that?

Tags: calculus

Wiki gives this definition of [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)

> In vector calculus, the gradient is a multi-variable generalization of the derivative. Whereas the ordinary derivative of a function of a single variable is a scalar-valued function, the gradient of a function of several variables is a vector-valued function.

Is it reasonable to claim that given a specific value of the independent variable(s), each fun has at most 1 gradient? how to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$(\nabla f)(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a_1,\ldots,a_n),\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\right),$$yes, it it exists, then it is unique.